# Puppetter fails due to node modules error

Tags: node.js, typescript, puppeteer

I am new to puppeteer and would appreciate as much help as possible.
My puppeteer tests build fails in travis ci. I am assuming the reason may be related to puppeteer's node_module. Any suggestion would be helpful.
There have been similar issues logged but with no solution provided. Here are some links of these issues:

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/833

https://api.travis-ci.com/v3/job/124937719/log.txt

https://travis-ci.com/BME-MIT-IET/Hmmm-iet-2018/jobs/124938746

My system config:

Puppeteer version:1.8.0

Platform / OS version: Mac > High Sierra

Node.js version: v8.12.0

npm : 6.4.1

This is the error message:

```
puppeteer@1.8.0 install /www/vhosts//node_modules/puppeteer
node install.js
/www/vhosts/node_modules/puppeteer/install.js:61
.then(() => browserFetcher.localRevisions())
^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
at startup (node.js:119:16)
at node.js:935:3
npm ERR! puppeteer@1.8.0 install: node install.js
npm ERR! Exit status 8
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the puppeteer@1.8.0 install script 'node install.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the puppeteer package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR! node install.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR! npm bugs puppeteer
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR! npm owner ls puppeteer
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Comment: What is the Node version configured for Travis?

Comment: node v0.10.42
npm  v3.8.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Puppeteer [documentation](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/README.md#usage):

> Puppeteer requires at least Node v6.4.0, but the examples below use async/await which is only supported in Node v7.6.0 or greater.

Your Travis configuration uses node v0.10.42 so you must upgrade it to atleast v6.4.0.

You can reference to Travis documentation on [Specifying Node.js versions](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/javascript-with-nodejs/#specifying-nodejs-versions). Here is a minimal setup:

**.travis.yml**:

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - "iojs"
  - "7"
```